# Multiplying two functions

Tags: r, function

Does anyone know how to multiply, or perform any binary operation, on two mathematical functions in R?

I'm trying to take something like:

```
f<-function(x){x+2}
g<-function(x){x}
```

and I want `h = f * g`, eventually to integrate `h`.  I need to do things like this many times, so entering `h` manually isn't a viable option.

Comment: Create a function named `h`? `h <- function(x) { f(x) * g(x) }`?

Comment: I tried that, but I can't figure out how to use it.  Neither h[2] nor h[[2]] gives me anything useful.

Comment: Why would you use square brackets there? Use `h(2)`, just as you would use any other function.

Comment: Because I have so many for loops in my code that I got so focused on square brackets.  And I'm stupid sometimes.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are going to be creating lots of multiplied functions, make a multiplier function that returns a function that is the product of its function arguments:

```
Multiply=function(a,b){
  force(a)
  force(b)
  function(x){a(x)*b(x)}
}
```

Then you can do:

```
 f<-function(x){x+2}
 g<-function(x){x}
 h=Multiply(f,g)
 h(1:5)
[1]  3  8 15 24 35
 f(1:5)*g(1:5)
[1]  3  8 15 24 35
```

And then:

```
h2=Multiply(f,f)
h2(1:5)
[1]  9 16 25 36 49
f(1:5)*f(1:5)
[1]  9 16 25 36 49
```

And you can use this with any function:

```
h3 = Multiply(sqrt,sin)
h3(1:5)
[1]  0.841471  1.285941  0.244427 -1.513605 -2.144220
sqrt(1:5)*sin(1:5)
[1]  0.841471  1.285941  0.244427 -1.513605 -2.144220
```

Any function you create with the `Multiply` function will be a function that returns the element-wise product of the two functions.

Programming with functions like this is often very useful. There's an R package, `functional`, that has some functions for this kind of thing, including `Compose` which is like your case but constructs `f(g(x))` rather than `f(x)*g(x)`:

```
require(functional)
z=Compose(sqrt,sin)
z(1:5)
[1] 0.8414710 0.9877659 0.9870266 0.9092974 0.7867491
sin(sqrt(1:5))
[1] 0.8414710 0.9877659 0.9870266 0.9092974 0.7867491
```

Note that its always round brackets (parentheses) because these are still functions. They just happen to have been created by other functions.

Note also the use of `force` in the `Multiply` function - this is because the arguments `a` and `b` aren't evaluated when the `Multiply` function is called - they only get evaluated when the returned function is called. If either `f` or `g` is changed or deleted before `h` is called, then without the `force` then `h` will get the value of `f` and `g` at the time `h` is called, rather than the time it was defined. This can lead to some infuriatingly hard-to-find bugs.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I already had an answer for my current purposes, but what you pointed out is a strategy that will surely help me in the future.  Thanks for being so thorough.

Comment: I was able to use this answer to solve a problem I was having. Thanks.