# multiplying functions

Tags: r, function

Suppose I have two numeric functions in R. Eg., cos and exp. What is the fastest way to have a new function object f(x) = cos(x)*exp(x)? I could define this as

```
f <- function(x) {cos(x)*exp(x) }
```

but is there a shorthand way of doing this (f = cos*exp for example)

Comment: that's not short enough? you could remove the {} and spaces and use = instead of <- ..

Comment: this seems tedious to do every time i want to multiply two functions. It seems strange that I have to define my own multiply function  multiply=function(f,g){h = function(x){f(x)*g(x)}; return(h) }

Comment: "every time I want to multiply two functions" --- multiplying two functions is just `cos(x) * exp(x)`. You do have to type a *little bit* more to create a new function that is the same as multiplying two functions.

Comment: i belatedly realized that this question has already been asked. there's a good answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823228/multiplying-two-functions?rq=1) along with a reference to a package called 'functional' that seems like it would be useful. I don't know how to mark my own question as a duplicate.

Comment: I'm surprised the great answer there didn't formulate a binary operator. I added the `force()` lines to my answer here as they're a very good idea to make it work reliably with user-defined functions.

Comment: yeah. the binary operator is a good idea. at least if i'm going to do this operation a lot. can you explain a bit more in your answer why you use force? Thanks.

Comment: `force` makes sure the functions are evaluated/defined at the time when the binary operator is created. See the *Lazy Evaluation* section here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're doing this a lot, you could define a binary operator:

```
"%*f%" = function(x, y) {
    force(x)
    force(y)
    function(z) x(z) * y(z)
}

f = cos %*f% exp
x = runif(10)

> identical(f(x), cos(x) * exp(x))
[1] TRUE
```

This has the advantage of being chain-able:

```
g <- cos %*f% exp %*f% log %*f% mean
g(x) # works appropriately
```