# How to manipulate and store functions in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop, multiplication, probability-density

I want to implement a Bayesian learning procedure, and more specifically I want to obtain one function at each of the `times` iterations of a for loop, which means that at the end of the procedure I wish to get a list with a number `times` of functions (this number of course is passed as a function argument).

So at each step I need to first multiply two functions and normalize them (meaning its integral sums up to 1) and store the resulting function (a posterior density) in a list, which will be used for the product of the next iteration.

First I tried basic function multiplication, in this way

```
function(data,times=1) {

  func <- list()
  posterior <- function(x) {1}
  for(i in seq(times)) {
    f0 <- function(x) {1/sqrt(2*pi*2)*exp(-0.25 * (data[i]-x)^2)}
    new_f <- function(x) {f0(x) * posterior(x)}
    normvalue <- integrate(new_f,  lower=-10, upper=10)$value
    fnorm <- function(x) {1/normvalue}
    posterior <- function(x) new_f(x)*normvalue(x)
    func <- c(func,list(posterior))
 }
 return(func)
}
```

This produces an infernal error `Error: evaluation nested too deeply: infinite recursion / options(expressions=)?
Error during wrapup: Error during wrapup: Error during wrapup: Error during wrapup: Error during wrapup: Error during wrapup: Error during wrapup: Error during wrapup:`, so I read [Multiplying two functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20823228/multiplying-two-functions) and tried the following

```
function(data,times=1) {

  Multiply=function(a,b){
    force(a)
    force(b)
    function(x){a(x)*b(x)}
  }

  func <- list()
  posterior <- function(x) {1}
  for(i in seq(times)) {
    f0 <- function(x) {1/sqrt(2*pi*2)*exp(-0.25 * (data[i]-x)^2)}
    new_f <- Multiply(f0,posterior)
    normvalue <- integrate(new_f,  lower=-10, upper=10)$value
    fnorm <- function(x) {1/normvalue}
    posterior <- Multiply(new_f,fnorm)
    func <- c(func,list(posterior))
  }

  return(func)
}
```

Now it doesn't produces any error, but the functions in the list `func` change as the variables `f0` and `normvalue` change in next iterations. In this manner, the only correctly saved function will be the last one in the list, and it makes no sense to call this function several times to obtain the successive densities.

How do I get this working and return all required functions in just one function call?

Comment: I don't get what the function is supposed to do. Explain it better, maybe making an example with some fake `data` and the corresponding objects you want as a result. You are saying that you want to implement some bayesian analysis, but it's not clear to me where is the prior and the likelihood. Please describe your model.

Comment: `data` is supposed to be any a numeric vector, for example `runif(50,-10,10)`. At each iteration I obtain the posterior density `p(theta|D)` where `theta` in this case is the mean parameter `mu` of a normal density and `D` the successive items in data: at each iteration `D` increases its length by one, meaning you have more information about the `theta` parameter so its density given `D` is successively refined at each step.

Comment: The prior is implicit in the integration, i.e., `p(theta)` is uniform on `[-10,10]`, the `likelihood` is the function `f0`. As I said I want to get the successive posteriors in one function call. Hope I explained myself now.

Comment: Just read today your comments. You should however state what your function should return. Just stating "the posterior" is not enough. Do you want a function to be returned? The mean value of the posterior? Its parameters? Please, as I asked before, edit your question adding the wanted return value for an example of `data`.

Comment: From my original post "which means that at the end of the procedure I wish to get a list with a number `times` of functions". Yes, the posteriors are supposed to be functions of the mean of the Gaussian. I can't make it clearer for you.